# WCF service adds :# to JSON object

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

Having never played with WCF services before, I decided to add an AJAX enabled WCF service to a project to see how it compared to ASMX.  In this example there's simply a post request to get a list of objects which are serialized into JSON.  The only thing that I could tell was different was that with the ASMX and WCF was that in the type property of the JSON array returned the WCF service added `:#` to the end of the __type property.  What's the reasoning behind this? (And also the type property shows up and the end of the property list in WCF vs. the beginning of the property list in ASMX

```
ASMX Service
__type: "Person", PersonId:123, FirstName: "joe", LastName: "smith"
WCF
__type: "Person:#", PersonId: 123, FirstName: "joe", LastName: "smith"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:#` portion of the type hint in WCF is the namespace. It adds another level of functionality over what was available to an ASMX Service (the two use different serializers to serialize the JSON).

You can read more about it in the *Polymorphism* section of:

[Stand-Alone JSON Serialization - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Good to know, I started the foray into WCF recently after realizing there's no reason to beat the dead ASMX horse.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't bother with WCF either. I would just straight into Web API - http://www.asp.net/web-api